# Rotate multiple data from many rows and combine them into one column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a certain type of data :

[image]

As we can see, I have many rows of the same size of cells in them (4) and the number of columns change accordingly to how much data I input.

What I would like to end up with, is something like this :

[image]

[image]

Either of this version works for me, so simply put I would need to use something similar to the `=TRANSPOSE()` function which flips the rows 90 degrees and then somehow combine the data from all the columns into one column. Any ideas?

EDIT ^ Above problem is resolved but I got another issue.

Now I would need to make something like this:

[image]

I would need to `FLATTEN()` the size1_x parts and then "copy" information on the left and on the right of that row to the flattened version of the table.

The expected outcome would need to be like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FLATTEN` function:

```
=FLATTEN(B2:E5)
```

or

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(B2:E5),FLATTEN(B2:E5)<>"")
```

if you don't want blanks

[image]

Comment: Oh my lord, I swear I was googling similar function for 15minutes and I couldnt get anything, yes the flatten() is perfect for me! Thank you so much and sorry for asking such a dumb question.

Comment: I just posted an EDIT with another problem with the =flatten() function, I forgot I needed somehow to copy the informations too, could you maybe take a look?

Comment: @KamilCiesielski It is better to publish a new question because the original one was answered.

Comment: Oh normally I would but it seems I cant post any new questions :(

Comment: Unfortunately I cant post a new question so im not sure what should I do right now? Because I would lov to get some more help from you